# Is it a good idea to always use bold or italic keywords for SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, keywords

Is it a good idea to always use **bold** or *italic* keywords in the page contents for SEO (Google)?

(not programmatically, but in the most of cases, near the totality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is semantically justified to use bold/italic (that means, if the visitor will benefit from it), go ahead. But search engines today are smart. The ranking of the page in search hits mostly corresponds to the quality of the content (and how well it fits the title/description of the page) rather than counting words that are `<strong>`or `<em>`.

Comment: Slight tangent/addition... from an SEO/Google perspective, `<strong>` and `<b>` are treated the same, as are `<em>` and `<i>`, according to a [video by Matt Cutts](http://youtu.be/0EE163OGjfo).

Comment: well, I think it depends if statistically is it good for conversion or not, since some argue italics are less readable (not me)